# datepicker how to add in cake php we need for steps

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

**jquery date picker for cake php installation steps  **

```
   php echo $this->Form->input("date", array('label' => "Date : ", 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'fl tal vat w300p', 'error' => false , 'id' => 'select_date')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->div('datepicker_img w100p fl pl460p pa', $this->Html->image('calendar.png'),array('id' => 'datepicker_img')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->div('datepicker fl pl460p pa', ' ' ,array('id' => 'datepicker')); ?>
```

Comment: You missed <? on first line

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is a place to get help with problems not to get your work done by others for you, please read this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7):

Hope this will help you :

**Steps :**

1) Download Jquery UI library from http://jqueryui.com/download/. In my case I have downloaded version 1.8.22 library. Extract downloaded zip folder.

2) Copy \js\jquery-ui-version.custom.min.js file to \app\webroot\js\jquery-ui-version.custom.min.js 
If you have not included jquery main file then also copy
\js\jquery-version.min.js file to \app\webroot\js\jquery-version.min.js

3) Copy  \css\ui-lightness\jquery-ui-version.custom.css file to \app\webroot\css\jquery-ui-version.custom.css

4) Copy all images from \css\ui-lightness\images.. to \app\webroot\img\…

5) Open \app\webroot\css\jquery-ui-version.custom.css file and replace “images/” text(path) with “../img/”.

6) Open view file and include following three lines : I have mentioned my file names here.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css(‘jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom’); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script(‘jquery-1.8.2.min’); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script(‘jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min’); ?>
```

7) Add a div with id “datepicker” where you want to display calender

```
<div style="height:500px;">
        <div style="clear:both;float:left;padding-left:60px;"><H1>DatePicker Example</H1></div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->create(false); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input("date", array('label' => "Date : ", 'type' => 'text', 
                                'class' => 'fl tal vat w300p', 'error' => false , 'id' => 'select_date')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->div('datepicker_img w100p fl pl460p pa', 
                            $this->Html->image('datepicker_calendar_icon.gif'),array('id' => 'datepicker_img')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->div('datepicker fl pl460p pa', ' ' ,array('id' => 'datepicker')); ?>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
```

8) Add following javascript code at end of the file.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              $("#datepicker_img img").click(function(){
                     $("#datepicker").datepicker(
                    {
                           dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                           onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
                                 $('#select_date').val(dateText);
                                 $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
                          }
                     }
                     );
               });
        });
```

Comment: it's working very nice post .....