# how to add datepicker in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

this solvedd my inserting data into input field but now i want to insert time stamp by not using the inputfield

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input("date", array('label' => "Date : ", 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'fl tal vat w300p', 'error' => false , 'id' => 'select_date')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->div('datepicker_img w100p fl pl460p pa', $this->Html->image('calendar.png'),array('id' => 'datepicker_img')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->div('datepicker fl pl460p pa', ' ' ,array('id' => 'datepicker')); ?>
```

I have used the above code for date picker, now i want the timestamp to use in my cakephp.

Sometimes it storing the exact timestamp and some times it is not storing it just using '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000' value in the database.

if there is any code can any one please help me with the code
thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datepicker how to add in cake php we need for steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687702/datepicker-how-to-add-in-cake-php-we-need-for-steps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687702/datepicker-how-to-add-in-cake-php-we-need-for-steps

Comment: You just check the date format before saving in the database. Database accepts only 'Y-m-d h:i:s' format. If the format is different then this will save 00000 as above

Comment: What format is the datepicker using when the form is posted?

Comment: ya i got the answer but now i not able to store the time stamp

Answer (score 0):

Please add this script in your view

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        $( "#YourTableNameYourField").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange:"-100:+50"
        });

    });
    </script>
```

And your input will  be same as

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('YourTableName' , array('action'=>'YourAction') );?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('YourField',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'class'=>'form-control','required'=>
```

Comment: without using javascript